# How to exclude a line from being printed in terminal on Mac OS

Tags: terminal, grep, zsh

I am trying to use `grep` to filter my terminal commands.
When searching the entire pc for a certain term I get a few results I want to exclude.
I use the following command taken from [this tutorial](http://osxdaily.com/2018/04/05/how-exclude-word-grep-command-line/).

```
sudo find / -iname "searchterm" | grep -v "exclude from search term"
```

For some reason my terminal still prints every line containing the excluded search term.

My `grep` version is `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD` according to `grep --version`. I have also installed `grep` via homebrew and executed the above command with `ggrep` instead of `grep` with the same results.

I use this command quite a lot and would like to find a less verbose method to use it. Does anyone know what I am missing here?

UPDATE: 
Since my question might have been misleading. I want to suppress lines from the output to the terminal, but not from the search result.
I repeaditly use `sudo find / -iname "searchterm"` to search for leftover files after uninstalling an application. Even with the sudo command I still get multiple lines of `find: /some/path/*: Operation not permitted`. This verbose output makes it difficult to find the files that I am actually looking for.

Comment: You do not need grep here. `find` is already using RegEx and has a not operator for doing exclusions. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-command-exclude-ignore-files/

Comment: I think my question was misleading. I will edit the question in a second. I want to suppress the lines saying `Operation not permitted` that I get when I search from the systems root directory.
So `sudo find / -iname "autodesk" ! -iname "Operation not permitted"` will still print all the lines saying `Operation not permitted`.

Comment: Any reason to not use `mdfind -name "searchterm"` as that would use macOS' Spotlight index and be much faster than scanning the entire disk like `find` does?

Comment: @j.unruh The `operation not permitted` messages go to `stderr`, not `stdout`, you could try `sudo find 2> /dev/null ...` to send the errors to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @SegFault thank you very much. Both of your solutions seem to be working. It is essential for me to not miss any files. I also have used this technique to remove malware from a friends computer. Does `mdfind` find all files? Hidden ones and also those that have only been created a few seconds ago?

Comment: @j.unruh The operating system indexes a file as part of it being created. I'm not positive on this point, but I think it is technically in the index before you can see it in the file system: in some sense, it will find files that are *about* to be created :)